# how to clear/ remove recently appended directive in ng-repeat while appending new directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to clear the previously appended `select` tag (using another directive) while appending the new one, so at a time only one `select` will be available on the screen.

At the moment I have this

[image]

My code

```
//Here is the "addRules" directive I have created: 
<script>
.directive('addRules', function($compile){
        return{ 
            scope:{},
            restrict:"A",
            template:'<a ng-click="appendSelect()" href="javascript:void(0)">Add Rules</a>', 
            link:function(scope,elem,attr){
                scope.appendSelect = function(){
                    var importSelect = $compile('<aadropdownmultiselect maxlenghttoshowselectedvalues="3" onchangeeventofcheckbox="setTabDirty()" model="selectedOptions" multiselectoptions="options"></aadropdownmultiselect>')(scope);
                    elem.append(importSelect);
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>
//And the HTML:
<table><tr>
<td add-rules></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How about using `elem.removeChild(child)` to remove a specific child. Or `elem.innerHTML=' '` in order to remove all children.

Comment: thanks for comment! 
I have used  **var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.itemtoappend' ) );**
                        myEl.remove();   //removes element